# Sort by Date in Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I would like to sort informations by date. For example data format is : Nov 10, 2017. I am trying something like this:

```
RealmResults<ResultFavorite> resultFavoritesReleaseDate = realm.where(ResultFavorite.class).sort("releaseDate", Sort.DESCENDING).findAll();
```

But it doesn't work. The fieldName in query is a String.

Comment: If you want to sort String in ascending order, then your date format should have been `yyyy-MM-dd`, and not `MMM dd, yyyy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say 'it doesn't work', I'm assuming that in actual fact the records *are* sorted, but in string descending order rather than date order.

There are two options that I can see.

Firstly, `Date` is a supported Realm field type, so you could change your field to be of that type (or an optional: `Date?` if using Kotlin). Your query as is should then work. This would be the preferred solution.

The second option is far less elegant, but would be necessary if you are unable to change the field type. In that case you would need to query all objects, and then map the result type to an array, and sort using a java or Kotlin sort routine. The sort criteria would be on a conversion from the String to a Date. This is slow and inefficient in terms of memory usage too.

Comment: I didn't know that in Realm is Date field type. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using different approach to get data from realm which does sorting the results in different way. My case is probably not relevant to the the exact case in  the question but still could help someone to do the sorting.
Sorted is the function where you must define the sorting field and true/false for descending/ascending order.

```
const realm = await RealmSetup.getMyInstance(parameter);
const resultList = realm.objects<MyType>('schemaName').sorted('createdDate', true);
return resultList as unknown as MyType[];
```